# Approve access token request - Oauth2 in Apex - ORDS

Tags: web-services, oauth-2.0, oracle-ords

I created an application that's calling Oracle RESTful Webservices and i want to secure them with Oauth 2.0. I followed this tutorial '[Accessing the RESTful Services from a Third Party Application](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html#accessing_the_restful_services_from_a_third_party_application)'

But when I try to get the access token, I get the error below: https://server:port/i/oauthdemo/gallery.html#error=access_denied&state=STATE

This document mentions that this error happens if the user denies the request. How can i approve the request? Is there any extra configuration that I need to make?

Comment: What version of ORDS do you have deployed?

Comment: i replied to your thread on the OTN forums https://community.oracle.com/thread/4177707

Comment: @AdrianP I'm using ords 18.3